# How to upload laravel app to shared hosting

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

My question may be stupid but, the question is that my client want to see my work progress on daily basis, but i am developing app in local environment , so my question is that how can i work on local and reflect changes in server

Comment: Google continuous integration. Might help

Comment: Using a IDE like PHPStorm is a great option. You can tell such an IDE to upload every updated file to a specific server automatically, so no need for manual uploading.

Answer (score 1):

You can try serving the pages with Laravel Valet.

You would need to allow access via your router to the port you are serving from or may be able to hit if you know your ip address.

Check out the docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/valet#serving-sites

Also, checkout the steps outlined here:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-laravel-valet-for-a-super-quick-dev-server

Specifically, step 5 refers to your end goal.

Comment: valet for mac users only and I didn't think it helps in his situation.

Answer (score 0):

simple. after making and test any changes, upload the changed file to the server.

**B.S.** after the first upload of laravel project files and folders, almost you need to upload is these folders **app**, **resources** and **routes**.

Comment: so what you are saying is ,i have to check manually which files to upload daily.

Comment: why daily?! also, you can use FTP software which offers auto upload to the changed file.

Comment: also, you can use software like TeamViewer to share your screen with your client

Comment: You can upload only the changed files with a tool like: beyond compare: https://www.scootersoftware.com

Comment: ok , so far best thing i can say is FTP , tell me what FTP software is best that only uploads the changed files , would be helpful

Comment: You can use [Rundeck](http://rundeck.org/) and Git to pull changes and update your instance every now and then (FTP is old school).

Answer (score 0):

Serving Laravel on shared hosting is really not recommended, or at least very complex. Laravel uses composer to install it's dependencies, a simple solution to that is to upload all the files manually, that might work yes, but there's the issue of the public path and file permissions.
Changing the configuration of the public path can be done easily in Laravel, but server side can be complex/inaccessible. Same goes for permissions.

---

**TL;DR**

You can try to upload all you files to the shared hosting via FTP/File Manager.
But some configuration regarding paths and permissions must be done.

---

**Notable alternative**

Using ngrok to share your local progress via a secure server behind a firewall

Learn more about **ngrok** [here](https://ngrok.com/)